# Extra Question mark in XML request. Is it Byte order mark?

Tags: xml, tomcat6, byte-order-mark

I am making calls to some SAAJ services.

The SAAG Service receives the XML with an extra question mark appended to it.
Why is there a extra question mark in the xml sent?

Received SOAP message:

```
?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Error:

```
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server.Unknown</faultcode><faultstring>com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl while dispatching SOAP request: **XML declaration parsing failed**</faultstring><faultactor></faultactor><stackTrace xmlns="http://www.ssaglobal.com/OpenWorld/c4soap">com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: XML declaration parsing failed&#13;
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.lookForXmlDecl(Unknown Source)&#13;
```